# Using array to display Win32_SystemDriver query results in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

So I am trying to get Description information from Win32_SystemDriver into a `RichTextBox`, but I am not able to do that because it only displays the last result from the query. As you can see bellow I tried to build an array but it does not work.

```
ObjectQuery query8 = new ObjectQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver"); 

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher8 = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query8);

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
{
    string[] arrTeamMembers = new string[] { queryObj["Description"].ToString() };
    foreach (var item in arrTeamMembers)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = item;
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideia how can I display all the info listing into the `RichTextBox`?

Comment: Try using a `StringBuilder` to append the text you need from each item, and then display the content of the string builder after the loop.

Comment: Use AppendText() instead.

Comment: It actually did the same. It will list everything in the same line and only displays the last result @MattJones

Comment: Does not work @HansPassant

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
List<string> arrTeamMembers = new List<string>(); 
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
{
    arrTeamMembers.Add(queryObj["Description"].ToString());
}
richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(",", arrTeamMembers);
```

Comment: It works. The only thing I've changed was change this richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(",", arrTeamMembers); to this richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrTeamMembers);

Comment: Why are you only getting one result?  You are using a foreach which expects multiple items.  Code doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is ok. There is one thing which you missed: `richTextBox1.Text` is a so-called property that stores a string. Now the reason why it shows you only the last driver is that you set this property to a new value for each driver you have in your array. So for the first driver it sets it to "driverA" and for the second to "driverB". What you are looking for is the `+=` operator --> `richTextBox1.Text += item;`. If you want to add spaces between the drivers you can do something like `richTextBox1.Text += $" {item}";`. This way you have a leading whitespace but formating is personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that ManagementObjectSearcher are IDisposable and therefore should be disposed.

```
ObjectQuery query8 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver");
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher8 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query8))
{
   List<string> arrTeamMembers = new List<string>(); 
  foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher8.Get())
  {
      arrTeamMembers.Add(queryObj["Description"].ToString());
  }
  richTextBox1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrTeamMembers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query8 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SystemDriver");
var searcher8 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query8);
var strbuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var queryObj in searcher8.Get())
    strbuilder.AppendLine($"{queryObj["Description"].ToString()}");

richTextBox1.Text = strbuilder.ToString();
```